# How to get bone rotation between two matrices?

Tags: scripting

Before the question a bit of a **background**...

I have a mesh, and vertex groups as well for it's bones. Before placing the bones, I moved the vertices of the mesh, so every `vertex.co += m.translation`, where m was a matrix containing a starting position for each bone. Because Blender is handling bones different then the system I was working on before, I had to do a conversion: while I have points in old system, Blender has "sticks" (what are described with two points: with a head and a tail). I was able to create an armature good enough just by telling Blender that a bone's head is the parent's tail, etc. There was no rotation applied on starting position. The stuff seemed to be fine: I even verified the result in Ultimate Unwrap 3D Pro, and seemed to be all right. So far it was too easy. Then it came for animations...

I had to do a bit research: made a primitive mesh and armature with a script and started to learn how Blender handles the bones and animations. I learned, that I can use a `.matrix` to rotate, and scale the bone relative to the parent. Using translation led to no good, since the bones are connected and so the parent's tail is the inherited's head, so if I would want translation I had to set length of the bone. In my old system everything was different, not just handling the bones. No head or tail, just matrices, so when I say a bone is in `m` then all the vertices are to be multiplied with it. `m` is not relative to parent, but the object.

So **my question is** the conversion... let's see only one bone in pose mode.

I have two matrices in my old system `m1` and `m2`, where `m1` is parent. I can make a bone in Blender system called `b` with a `.head` of `m1` and `.tail` of `m2`. Both `m1` and `m2` contain translation, rotation and scaling. In Blender I think it is like `b.head = m1.translation` and I am to point the bone to `m2.translation`, but with `m1.` rotation and scaling data, but ignoring `m2.` translation and scaling, because that is the inherited bone's property. My guess is that I am to modify the rotation value with `m2.translation` value somehow, but I do not know how.

I am not good enough in BPY yet and Math ever, that is why I would like to ask for help with this.

Comment: I think you need to give quite a bit more detail. **"how I can get the bone's matrix value?"** - Editmode? Object Mode? Pose Mode?, What is the matrix relative to?, The question title asks for the **"bone rotation between two matrices?"**, but the question isnt asking about rotation at all. Ideally you could give a sample script which currently fails, then its easier to test and show the solution. (also probably more useful to others)

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I will edit the question (had no time for details this time).

Comment: @Zéiksz I had a similar issue here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3549/how-can-a-bones-tail-be-changed-by-a-script/3553#3553. This is the first step to convert position data from kinect into rotation matrices. This might be helpful for you since it shows how to calculate rotation from positions.

Comment: Any updates to this quesiton?

Comment: No, and as far I remember I was unable to solve the issue those days.